# How to properly use bootstrap-select in a ASP MVC project

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

i'm having a problem with bootstrap-select, the console says "undefined" on the .selectpicker(); The link is at the top of the View and the Script at the bottom, both next to the twitter bootstrap call (CSS and JS both via CDN).. It's a bundling problem?

```
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel=" stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.2/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />'

<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel=" stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.2/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

```
<select id="selectFile" class="form-control selectpicker" data-style="btn-success" required>
   <option selected="selected" disabled>Select..</option>
   <option id="1">From File (Excel)</option>
   <option id="2">SQL DB (Contpaq)</option>
</select>
```

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.3/js/bootstrap-select.js"></script>
```

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();

    $('select.selectpicker').on('change', function () {
        var selected = $('.selectpicker option:selected').val();
        alert(selected);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i wasn't using (the below), i did not know about it til' i google a lot, now everything works just fine.. Thank you

`@section scripts {}`

Answer (score 0):

This error has been raised as you have not added  jquery reference.

Please add jquery reference before referring bootstrap.js.

Comment: No, i have the jQuery reference before the bootstrap reference.
1.- jQuery
2.- Bootstrap
3.- Bootstrap-select

Comment: Can you please verify the cdn you had added for bootstrap-select is valid. This issue happens when the js is not properly loaded. Its not problem of bundling since you had not used bundling .

Please try with cdn : http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/bootstrap-select.min.js

Comment: It worked with that CDN, but why isn't working with the local files?

Comment: Verify that scripts and css are loaded by checking view source functionality of the browser.